Looking for a better way to show column values in the same row
I have a SQL view:
DECLARE @StartDate date = '5/1/2024'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '5/31/2024'

SELECT DISTINCT
    i.IncidentNumber,
    i.ReportNumber
FROM 
    MV_Incident AS i WITH (nolock)
WHERE 
    i.IncidentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate) 
ORDER BY
    i.IncidentNumber

that returns data like this:

But I'd prefer that each row have a unique 1st-column value and that any multiple values in the 2nd column be shown in a 3rd column (or 4th or 5th, if there are that many).

Now, I can get it to work if I use sub-queries:
SELECT DISTINCT
    i.IncidentNumber,
    (SELECT i2.ReportNumber 
     FROM MV_Incident AS i2 WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE i2.IncidentNumber = i.IncidentNumber 
     ORDER BY i2.ReportNumber OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY) AS ReportNumber1,
    (SELECT i2.ReportNumber 
     FROM MV_Incident AS i2 WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE i2.IncidentNumber = i.IncidentNumber
     ORDER BY i2.ReportNumber OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY) AS ReportNumber2

but this runs pretty slowly.
Is there a better way I can accomplish this?
Many thanks to anyone that can assist.

We don't post images of sample data/results here.

Also, those "with (nolock)" hints are not the automatic go faster items you've likely been led to believe.

(1) Use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IncidentNumber ORDER BY ReportNumber) to assign sequence numbers to the reports. (2) Use PIVOT to convert rows to columns.

Does this answer your question? Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns

Consider using string_agg to aggregate them into one column.

The SQL language has a strict rule: you MUST know the number of columns in the result set at query compile time, before looking at ANY data. It violates that rule when you can have dynamic columns like this. You have two options to get around it:

Pick a reasonable maximum number of columns, and build the query based of that max number.
Run the query in three steps: First run a query to determine how many columns you'll need. Then use that result to build a new query on the fly. Finally, run the generated query.

Both options are painful to write and slow the execute, typically needing an extra additional complete pass through the entire source dataset for each potential column. PIVOT/CrossTab techniques help, but you still need to know about what columns you want to pivot. This is painful because this requirement violates the relational set theory that underpin all SQL databases. With that in mind, you'll often have better results by returning the data as it is, and making this pivot in your client code or reporting tool.
